# AWS SignInProviderResultAdapter.onCognitoError() can create account but crashes on login

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-cognito

I am very new to AWS. I finally got it to work. I used this as my main code:

```
package elthran.testingaws;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.ui.SignInUI;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSStartupHandler;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSStartupResult;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;

public class AuthenticatorActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authenticator);

        // Add a call to initialize AWSMobileClient
        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, new AWSStartupHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(AWSStartupResult awsStartupResult) {
                SignInUI signin = (SignInUI) AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getClient(
                        AuthenticatorActivity.this,
                        SignInUI.class);
                signin.login(
                        AuthenticatorActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class).execute();
            }
        }).execute();
    }

}
```

It opened a basic login window and let me create an account. It registered in the AWS Federated Identities. Then I tried to log in to the app using my new account and I keep getting this error. Can anyone help explain why?

```
D/AWSRefreshingCognitoIdentityProvider: Storing the Refresh token in the loginsMap.
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Identity id is changed
                                     Saving identity id to SharedPreferences
                                     Clearing credentials from SharedPreferences
D/AWSRefreshingCognitoIdentityProvider: Storing the Refresh token in the loginsMap.
D/IdentityManager: SignInProviderResultAdapter.onCognitoError()
                   com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException: Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException; Request ID: 4d08f70c-b844-11e8-84be-85774fe09fa3)
                       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:730)
                       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
                       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
                       at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:566)
                       at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:389)
                       at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.populateCredentialsWithCognito(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:782)
                       at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:694)
                       at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:631)
                       at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:514)
                       at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getIdentityId(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:457)
                       at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.populateCredentialsWithCognito(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:776)
                       at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:694)
                       at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:631)
                       at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:514)
                       at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager.refreshCredentialWithLogins(IdentityManager.java:523)
                       at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager.access$800(IdentityManager.java:77)
                       at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager$3.run(IdentityManager.java:563)
                       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                   Signing out...
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Clearing credentials from SharedPreferences
E/SignInActivity: Sign-in with Amazon Cognito Your User Pools caused an error.
                  com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.signin.CognitoAuthException: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException: Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException; Request ID: 4d08f70c-b844-11e8-84be-85774fe09fa3)
                      at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager$SignInProviderResultAdapter.onCognitoError(IdentityManager.java:426)
                      at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager$SignInProviderResultAdapter.access$1000(IdentityManager.java:400)
                      at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager$3.run(IdentityManager.java:565)
                      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                   Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException: Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException; Request ID: 4d08f70c-b844-11e8-84be-85774fe09fa3)
                      at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:730)
                      at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
                      at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
                      at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:566)
                      at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:389)
                      at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.populateCredentialsWithCognito(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:782)
                      at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:694)
                      at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:631)
                      at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:514)
                      at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getIdentityId(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:457)
                      at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.populateCredentialsWithCognito(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:776)
                      at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:694)
                      at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:631)
                      at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:514)
                      at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager.refreshCredentialWithLogins(IdentityManager.java:523)
                      at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager.access$800(IdentityManager.java:77)
                      at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager$3.run(IdentityManager.java:563)
                      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Identity id is changed
                                     Saving identity id to SharedPreferences
                                     Clearing credentials from SharedPreferences
E/DefaultSignInResultHandler: Sign-in with Amazon Cognito Your User Pools failed.
                              com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException: Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException; Request ID: 4d08f70c-b844-11e8-84be-85774fe09fa3)
                              com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.signin.CognitoAuthException: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException: Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException; Request ID: 4d08f70c-b844-11e8-84be-85774fe09fa3)
                                  at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager$SignInProviderResultAdapter.onCognitoError(IdentityManager.java:426)
                                  at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager$SignInProviderResultAdapter.access$1000(IdentityManager.java:400)
                                  at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager$3.run(IdentityManager.java:565)
                                  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                               Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException: Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException; Request ID: 4d08f70c-b844-11e8-84be-85774fe09fa3)
                                  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:730)
                                  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
                                  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
                                  at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:566)
                                  at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:389)
                                  at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.populateCredentialsWithCognito(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:782)
                                  at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:694)
                                  at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:631)
                                  at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:514)
                                  at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getIdentityId(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:457)
                                  at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.populateCredentialsWithCognito(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:776)
                                  at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:694)
                                  at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:631)
                                  at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:514)
                                  at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager.refreshCredentialWithLogins(IdentityManager.java:523)
                                  at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager.access$800(IdentityManager.java:77)
                                  at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager$3.run(IdentityManager.java:563)
                                  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458) 
                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I have been having nothing but trouble with this. I want login to redirect to my MainActivity which is a simple "hello world" text page, just to make sure I have a working create user and login page. It seems there are so many possible issues and it's very hard for a beginner to read these error logs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are getting this error: Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException: Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool. Can you check the Unauthenticated role and Authenticated role of your Identity Pool and if they have the right policies?

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work now after adding new IAM roles.

Comment: I will take the feedback to the team to improve on the error message.